# ANOVA doesn't showing interaction in R between categorical variables

Tags: r, anova, interaction

I have three categorical variable "A", "B", "C" and one continuous variable E. I run anova but could not get the interaction between the three categorical variable.
Here is the dput(),if I am not wrong

```
              A           B                   C         E
104 KWS KERUBINO      Hybrid    Southern Europe  1.8301204
22          187R   Landraces       South America 4.8571096
29          191R   Landraces       South America 3.4260161
114     KWS 2376      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 3.1342468
142 KWS KAVALIER      Hybrid      Eastern Europe 1.7085775
110      KXB7554      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 2.2275519
14          187R   Landraces       South America 6.5711872
64          186R   Landraces       South America 3.1117281
98      KERAVNOS      Hybrid    Southern Europe  1.3315641
43          185R   Landraces       South America 2.7426597
128    KAPITOLIS      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 1.3510272
115   KLEOPATRAS      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 1.6293303
91         P3522      Hybrid                Asia 2.6662802
108      KXB7471      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 1.8594944
130    KAPITOLIS      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 1.8221993
106      KXB7471      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 2.5298627
27          191R   Landraces       South America 3.0800623
59          192R   Landraces       South America 3.5497222
116   KLEOPATRAS      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 2.2132572
39          185R   Landraces       South America 3.7028279
66          186R   Landraces       South America 1.9881630
111      KXB7554      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 4.3100911
12      PERU1101   Landraces       South America 4.5401075
58          192R   Landraces       South America 2.3414171
10      PERU1101   Landraces       South America 1.1254469
87         30V92      Hybrid                Asia 2.1524959
78          DHO2      Hybrid              Africa 2.9368893
95      KERAVNOS      Hybrid    Southern Europe  3.2170391
74           B73 Inbred line   widely caltivated 1.5387586
83      900MGOLD      Hybrid                Asia 2.0199581
121  KWS SMARAGD      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 0.9970583
32          191R   Landraces       South America 2.7492862
9          JUN82   Landraces       South America 6.7000000
102      KALUMET      Hybrid    Southern Europe  4.0086721
51          189R   Landraces       South America 3.5845065
107      KXB7471      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 1.7087873
2        ARGE467   Landraces       South America 2.7226495
90         P3522      Hybrid                Asia 1.6227942
140      KIDEMOS      Hybrid      Eastern Europe 0.7105006
33          191R   Landraces       South America 4.9887996
72          186R   Landraces       South America 3.3097711
16          187R   Landraces       South America 4.1256153
63          192R   Landraces       South America 4.3877888
45          185R   Landraces       South America 3.7732558
67          186R   Landraces       South America 8.0046451
7          JUN82   Landraces       South America 4.0540767
38          185R   Landraces       South America 5.3840801
61          192R   Landraces       South America 1.8931744
103      KALUMET      Hybrid    Southern Europe  2.4418376
81          DHO4      Hybrid              Africa 1.4373845
129    KAPITOLIS      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 1.3336781
21          187R   Landraces       South America 7.0386277
109      KXB7471      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 1.6033865
44          185R   Landraces       South America 2.7354487
24          191R   Landraces       South America 4.6558922
132      KXB8383      Hybrid      Central Europe 0.8552671
136       KENTOS      Hybrid      Central Europe 0.5022709
112     KWS 2376      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 2.6849360
93      KWS 5581      Hybrid    Southern Europe  4.4902268
1        ARGE467   Landraces       South America 2.2069407
48          185R   Landraces       South America 6.4855435
19          187R   Landraces       South America 3.4981968
6          JUN82   Landraces       South America 3.0287668
127      KXB8386      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 0.7057418
68          186R   Landraces       South America 2.2289599
99      KERAVNOS      Hybrid    Southern Europe  1.6680102
120  KWS SMARAGD      Hybrid Southeastern Europe 2.4786491
46          185R   Landraces       South America 2.6330783
138      KIDEMOS      Hybrid      Eastern Europe 1.4835855
37          185R   Landraces       South America 2.4803216
71          186R   Landraces       South America 1.5690705
```

Comment: Please share the data in `df2_sub` as a `dput()` so we can copy/paste the data into R.

Comment: Why the comments chars in the posted data?

Comment: Try `car::Anova(anova_df_sub)`, you have no degrees of freedom left in the interactions. Nor for the `B` and `C` 1st order effects.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.